# Why iterator is returned without actually calling .iterator?

Tags: dart

I am from Javascript and I do not understand the below concept. I am getting "(apple, orange)" as a result by executing the code below which is what I wanted. But I am wondering why I do not have to call the iterator function to get the iterator? Like "print(MyString(["apple","orange"]).iterator);"

```
void main() {
  print(MyString(["apple","orange"]));
}

class MyString extends Iterable<String>{
  MyString(this.strings);
  final List<String> strings;
  
  Iterator<String> get iterator => strings.iterator;
}
```

Comment: You are extending from `Iterable` which implements it's own `toString()` method: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Iterable/toString.html . You will therefore get this `toString()` method and not the one from `Object`.

Comment: @julemand101  but removing "Iterator<String> get iterator => strings.iterator;" doesn't work. If Iterable will implements it's own toString() method, what is the point of adding this? Thanks.

Comment: `Iterable` is an abstract class which does not come with any implementation for `get iterator`. So when you are extending from `Iterable`, you need to give an implementation for this. But `Iterable` comes with a lot of functionality which depends on the `get iterator` e.g. the `toString()` method from Iterable there will print the elements as documented in my previous link.

Comment: But, when you do `print(MyString(["apple","orange"]));`, you are not getting the `iterator` field, but `print` will call the `toString()` method on the `MyString` object. The `toString()` method from `Iterable` does not print all elements in all scenarios as documented as: "The default representation always contains the first three elements. If there are less than a hundred elements in the iterable, it also contains the last two elements.". The `toString()` method will use the `iterator` field but does not print all elements.

Comment: That's very well explained. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I will try write an answer based on this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are extending from `Iterable` which are an abstract class. This class contains a lot of methods but does not contain any implementation of `get iterator`. So when you extend from `Iterable`, you will need to give a implementation of this field.

One of the methods you get from `Iterable` is a `toString()` implementation which is the following:

```
String toString() => IterableBase.iterableToShortString(this, '(', ')');
```

So this `toString()` will now be used instead of the one from `Object` you will get by default.

The reason this matters is because when you do:

```
print(MyString(["apple","orange"]));
```

`print` is implemented so if the given object is not a `String`, it will call the `toString()` method on the object. So in your case, we are calling the `toString()` method on your `MyString` object. Since `MyString` does not implement `toString()` it will try find `toString()` in the class hierarchy from `MyString`. In your case, the nearest `toString()` implemented method is the one from `Iterable`.

The `toString()` method on `Iterable` is documented as:

> Returns a string representation of (some of) the elements of `this`.
>
> Elements are represented by their own `toString` results.
>
> The default representation always contains the first three elements. If there are less than a hundred elements in the iterable, it also contains the last two elements.
>
> If the resulting string isn't above 80 characters, more elements are included from the start of the iterable.
>
> The conversion may omit calling `toString` on some elements if they are known to not occur in the output, and it may stop iterating after a hundred elements.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Iterable/toString.html

This method are also using the `get iterator` field to output the elements. So this is why it seems like it "just works" when you do:

```
print(MyString(["apple","orange"]));
```

But you should note that `print` does actually not use the `get iterator` field directly but are just using the `String` returned from `toString()`. Also, `toString()` from `Iterable` does not output all elements from the `Iterable` as you can read in the documentation.